# compareWith directive in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, directive

> Angular 4 introduced `compareWith` directive to compare `options` to select.

```
<select [compareWith]="byUId" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers">
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user.UId">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is only applicable for `select` controls? or Is it possible to use other controls? if yes, then how can do it?

Comment: There is an open issue to add this for radio buttons, but no action taken yet: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28486. There are also a number of solutions suggested here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only for `select` tags. Here is the original *Pull Request* on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13349

Answer (score 0):

For me only solved when I've change the `ngModel` to `value`. Like:

```
<select [compareWith]="byUId" [(value)]="selectedUsers">
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user.UId">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```